# iPhone detecting ID numbers in email messages

Tags: ios

I am building an application for use by my company that has a number of features.  One thing I am interested in adding if at all possible is linking a specific format of internal ID to my application if it exists in an email, much the same way that UPS/USPS/FEDEX tracking numbers are converted into links in the email app.

Is it possible to build an app extension that would create a link from an ID that is in an email, and launch my application when it is clicked?

For example, if the following ID (**1453833784.127410**) is in the body or the subject of an email message, the end user could click it and have it launch the app.

My experience in app extensions is limited so any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There is no API that can hook into the Mail app (or any other app) such that text in a certain format gets translated into a URL for a 3rd party app.

If you have any control of the email generation, the creation of the original email should be updated to include the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom url schemes for example:

When user click the link yourapp://1453833784.127410 in the email if the app install it will open the app to handle the url via application:openURL:options: in app delegate

You can define custom url schemes in your app's Info.plist

```
URL types <Array>
  Item 0 <Dictionary>
    URL identifier <String> com.example.yourapp
    URL Schemes    <String> yourapp
```

This custom url schemes solution should work on Android app too.

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood the question.